# Why isn't Redis cache driver working for me in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

Specifically, `Cache::put` doesn't seem to be working for me. I've set the following items in my .env file, and I have the predis/predis library installed.

```
# redis + cache
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CACHE_DB=1
```

I have left the config files unmodified (they are using the above values.)

Then in my php code I have:

```
if (!empty($request->header('Authorization'))) {
        $token = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $request->header('Authorization'));
        // first check the cache for the user id
        Log::debug("attempting to get user id for token {$token} from cache");

        $response = json_decode(Cache::get($token, function() use ($request, $token) {
            Log::debug("token not found in cache, fetching");
            $auth_server = config('auth.oauth.auth_server');
            try {
                $response = $this->http->get("{$auth_server}/api/verify", [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => $request->header('Authorization'),
                        'Accept'        => 'Application/json'
                    ] 
                ]);
            }
            catch (ClientException $e) {
                $response = $e->getResponse();

                $json_response = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());

                $json_response->code = $response->getStatusCode();

                return $json_response;
            }

            $response_body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            $json = json_decode($response_body);

            if ($json->success) {
                Log::debug("adding cache with key $token and value $response_body");
                Cache::put($token, $response_body);
                return $response_body;
            }

            return null;
        }));
}
```

I have issued a `redis-cli monitor` command in the command line and while I can definitely see that it attempts to get from the cache, I never see a call to put things in the cache. I am currently on Laravel 5.7 if that makes any difference..

Comment: Is the `Log::debug("adding cache with key $token and value $response_body");` call firing?

Comment: yup, and the key and value aren't null. not sure why it wouldn't work except that maybe the key is too long?

Comment: ok, the reason is because you *must* specify an expiration. looks like it's working now. seems like this is a bug?

Comment: If you can reproduce it with a simpler example, file it as a bug. The docs say `If the storage time is not passed to the put method, the item will be stored indefinitely` at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache.